# Swagger UI doesn't show module name in its url and

Tags: swagger-2.0, springfox

I have followed https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-restful-api-documentation-with-swagger and developing the Swagger using the `springfox-swagger-ui` and `springfox-swagger2` version `2.9.2`.

I used the below configurations, but I want ***module-name*** to be printed out here. Also, `@Api(tags = "User Catalouge", description = "List Of Users")`, **description** is deprecated.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("guru.springframework.controllers"))
                .paths(regex("/product.*"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metaData());
    }
    private ApiInfo metaData() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "Spring Boot REST API",
                "Spring Boot REST API for Online Store",
                "1.0",
                "Terms of service",
                new Contact("John Thompson", "https://springframework.guru/about/", "john@springfrmework.guru"),
               "Apache License Version 2.0",
                "https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0");
        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the `servlet context path`. **Spring Boot & Swagger** are smart enough to recognized the URL and take it in the url.

```
server.servlet.context-path=/product-details
```